# How do I duplicate a django model instance, keeping a reference to the original?

Tags: django, django-orm

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) give an example of copying a model instance:

```
blog = Blog(name='My blog', tagline='Blogging is easy')
blog.save() # blog.pk == 1

blog.pk = None
blog.save() # blog.pk == 2
```

In a slightly more complicated scenario I have an `Article` which can point to a `Revision`, which keeps a reference to its parent (keeping a history of edits made). **I want to duplicate an existing `Revision`, setting the duplicate's `parent` to the original.**

```
class Article:
    revision = models.OneToOneField('Revision')

class Revision:
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Revision', related_name='children')
    content = models.TextField()

article = get_some_article()
revision = article.revision # ideally I want this to dupe the python object
revision.pk = None # but this create a copy instead
revision.content += " edited"
revision.parent = article.revision # this is the apparent problem
revision.save()
```

I think there are two issues with `revision.parent = article.revision`. One, it's a self reference, and two, it hasn't been saved yet so can't be referenced.

I might be able to do something like this, unless the instance is cached (?):

```
parent = Revision.objects.get(pk=article.revision.pk) #get a duplicate
...
revision.parent = parent
```

But this is bad because it involves a whole extra query just to duplicate the object. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
article = get_some_article()
revision = article.revision
revision.parent = revision # Set the parent to itself
revision.content += " edited"
revision.pk = None
revision.save()  # New revision with parent set to original
# Assuming you are keeping the latest revision reference in article you need to update that also.
article.revision = revision
article.save()
```

Comment: OK, so assigning the ForeignKey `parent` will copy the object's current `pk`, rather than store a reference to the whole object (which would then lose the `pk` value before `save()`)?

Comment: Yes, i am guessing your original method was also correct... because you were taking parent reference from article.revision so it should work correctly..

Comment: For self  parent reference parent can be set to object itself.

Comment: After actually testing it, my original method tells me I can't assign parent because the revision isn't in the database (having just set its `pk` to None), but assigning it first before setting `pk = None` seems to work just fine.